# How would I send all my data from one table to another,SQL?

Tags: sql

I want to transfer the data from one table in sql to another is there a way to do this ?

Comment: same structure between the tables ? (even the order of the columns ?)

Comment: Knowing the database (including version) would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this: [**Copying rows from other tables**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_%28SQL%29#Copying_rows_from_other_tables)

Answer (score 3):

You can use standard SQL for this, specifically the `insert..select` statement. Say you have the following table:

```
t1:
    f1 integer
    f2 varchar(50)
```

You can move data from that table to another similar table with:

```
insert into t2 (f1,f2) select f1, f2 from t1;
```

It doesn't have to be the same structure as long as the fields are compatible. If t2 is defined thus:

```
t2:
    f1 integer
    f2 varchar(7)
    f3 varchar(50)
```

you could do:

```
insert into t2 (f1,f2,f3) select f1, 'n/a', f2 from t1;
```

In addition. the select statement has all the regular options such as the `where` clause for limiting the amount of data copied, although some may not make sense (such as `order by`).

If you need the table itself copied (as well as copying data), `select..into` is the way to go:

```
select into t3 from t1;
```

This also allows a `where` clause which limits the data transferred.

If you need to transfer a *lot* of data and performance is important, you may want to consider one of the non-standard-SQL options such as unloading and reloading the table, or performance "tricks" like turning off indexing on the target table until after the data is transferred.